# How to auto-update installed fonts in Windows

Tags: windows, fonts

I use couple of open source fonts like Inter, Iosevka, Hack etc on Windows 10. Those fonts regularly get updated but it takes time to install a new version so I rarely or never do it.

I know some fonts are available on Windows Store which would solve the issue, but right now not a lot of fonts are there, none of the mentioned ones.

Comment: You don't mention what version of Windows you are using. Without that vital information, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Added info about Windows 10 and Window Store.

Comment: Check out a tool like chocolatey and whenever it provides packages for those fonts. You will probably have to come up with something of your own. You could probably build a PowerShell script for it. Also you'd have check what those updates actually entail and whenever it's worth the additional work.

Comment: That is the main issue... Not a lot of fonts are packaged, and those that are, are not maintained. I could become a packager and do the job, but I'm currently not a Chocholatey (or Scopp, or...) user and this font thing alone it's not tempting enough for me to become one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question...*

I ended up writting a simple PowerShell script. It will not install fonts, but it will find latest version, download a file and unzip it. Solve about 80% of my problem.

Here is a basic version of the script that will download latest releases of [Iosevka](https://github.com//be5invis/Iosevka/) and [Inter](https://github.com/rsms/inter) fonts:

```
$fonts = @(
             @("Iosevka", "be5invis"),
             @("Inter", "rsms") 
)

foreach ($font in $fonts)
{

  $apiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + $font[1] + "/" + $font[0] + "/releases/latest"
  $json = Invoke-WebRequest $apiUrl
  $o = ConvertFrom-Json $json
  $downloadUrl = $o.assets[0].browser_download_url

  $filename = $downloadUrl.Substring($downloadUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)    
  $localFilename = (Resolve-Path ".").Path + '\' + $filename

  if (Test-Path $localFilename)
  {

    "File $filename already exists! Skipping."

  } else {

    "Downloading $filename..."
    $progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
    $webResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $downloadUrl -UseBasicParsing
    $progressPreference = 'continue'
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($localFilename, $webResponse.Content) 

    "Expanding $filename..."
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $localFilename -DestinationPath $font[0] -Force

  }
}
```